# How to Two-way databind a TextBox's Text to a Dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, dependency-properties

I'm trying to two-way data bind a TextBox's Text property to the parent window's dependency property.

I've trimmed down the problem to just a few lines in a test project to try to get the binding to work, and have been googling around for days.

From the Xaml file:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding A, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding B, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"/>
    <Button Content="Random" Click="Button_Click" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and from the CS file:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));
    public double A
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AProperty, value);
            SetValue(BProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));
    public double B
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AProperty, value);
            SetValue(BProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        A = 0d;
        B = 1d;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        A = new Random().Next();
    }
}
```

When the window starts, both TextBox's show "1" (as expected because of the constructor). Clicking the button causes both TextBox's to update to a random number (also as expected).

But changing the text in either TextBox does not update the bound dependency property, hence it won't update the other TextBox.

There aren't any error messages during these operations.

Comment: If you want A to set B and vice versa, you should use callbacks. The setter of the CLR wrapper should only call SetValue of the dependency property itself and not do anything else.

Comment: In order to get immediate Text changes back to the Binding's source property, also specify `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the Bindings. Also be aware that WPF bypasses the property setters when a dependency property is set by a Binding. Do not call anything else than `SetValue(XProperty, value);` in the setter of a property `X`.

Comment: To get rid of some confusion here, you might move properties A and B into a view model, and make them regular CLR properties with an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

Comment: Why do you have two dependency properties rather than one if they're both supposed to be the same value?

Comment: @Andy It was just to see the effect in both boxes. The actual application is a calculator in a user control with multiple text boxes, I just didn't want to create a separate model from the view-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `A` to set `B` and vice versa, you should use callbacks. The setter of the CLR wrapper should *only* call `SetValue` of the dependency property itself and don't do anything else, e.g.:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAChanged)));

public double A
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(AProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnAChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow window = (MainWindow)d;
    window.B = window.A;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));
public double B
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(BProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
}
```

Also note that you should set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the bindings to `PropertyChanged` if you want the source property to be set for each keystroke. By default, they will be set when the `TextBox` loses focus.

Comment: All true, but here the two dependency properties are not target properties of any Binding, but source properties instead. The setters will be called.

Comment: @Clemens: That's right. I removed that part as it's not related to the question.

Comment: OP will also not strictly need PropertyChangedCallbacks... The core problem seems just the missing UpdateSourceTrigger

Comment: Thanks, it was the PropertyChangedCallbacks, and I wasn't aware of the convention in the setters (thanks for that article link). I had previously removed the UpdateSourceTrigger from my example because it had no effect whether present or not.